# Save changes to DataGridView (filled using MySqlHelper) into MySql database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to update a MySQL database on the basis of changes in the DataGridView.

I'm currently using this code to fill the DGV:

```
Private Sub Load_in_DGV_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btn_Load_in_DGV.Click
    Dim ds As DataSet '= New DataSet
    Dim mTbl As DataTable
    Dim sqlQRY$ = "SELECT `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Age` FROM `persons` WHERE `Age` > 25"
    ds = MySqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(CnStr, sqlQRY)
    mTbl = ds.Tables(0)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = mTbl
End Sub
```

But all post and guides I read seem to use a DataAdapter and not to use MySqlHelper, so I'm asking if it's possible to save changes to database using my current code (and what's the way) and, otherwise, what are minimum changes to do in my code.

I know there is the command "mysqlhelper.UpdateDataSet" which has the following syntax:

```
Public Shared Sub UpdateDataSet (_
ConnectionString ByVal As String, _
CommandText ByVal As String, _
ByVal ds As DataSet, _
ByVal TableName As String _
)
```

but I have not found any example of use.
I did not understand what to send as "commandText".

Comment: are you getting an error, if so what is it?

Comment: @user3697824 No. I am a self-taught and simply can't find a tutorial or an example to update the database from a DGV filled as I do. So I do not know if it's possible or not.

Comment: based on what is there, the helper doesnt do a great deal for you.  Since there are *loads* of resources like MSDN for using a DataAdpter, you might consider using that approach.  Otherwise, this is not the place for tutoring or asking for offsite resources

Comment: I@user3697824 I added a specific request (which I avoided to make room for more solutions). I hope now you can give me an answer.

Comment: `CommandText` would be the SQL query...same as with a DataAdapter.  BTW, `UpdateDataSet` is a method, not a "command".

Comment: @user3697824 So CommandText is like `UPDATE persons SET FirstName = 'Mandy' WHERE Age = 20`? So  I can't use it to save all changes to DGV?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90915/discussion-between-genespos-and-user3697824).

Comment: The DataAdapter is very very easy to use.  Give it a SQL SELECT query and you can use CommandBuilder to build the corresponding update command.  then it is mot much more than `myDA.Update()` to pass all the info from the DGV to the database.  [See this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1z2bkx2(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)